# AWS S3 Get Object Part Metadata

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-net

I am trying to get information about Number of Parts and Part Size for an uploaded Object in S3 using .Net C# SDK.
The below commandlet returns PartsCount and ContentLength (Part Size).

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket MY_BUCKET_NAME --key MY_OBJECT_KEY --part-number 1
```

In the SDK there is a method to retrieve Object MetaData - GetObjectMetaDataAsync() but it returns the metadata of the file and not a specific part e.g. PartsCount property is always null. This seems to be the equivalent of:

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket MY_BUCKET_NAME --key MY_OBJECT_KEY
```

I am trying to find an overload or some param that would allow me to pass in a part number. It seems that it is currently not supported. But the GetObjectMetadataResponse has properties for PartsCount, which is always Null in my case.

Can anyone suggest a way to get information about NumberOfParts and PartSizes for a particular Object using AWS C# SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Silly oversight on my part. GetObjectMetadataRequest class has a property to request for a specific Part Number.

```
var getObjectMetadataRequest = new GetObjectMetadataRequest()
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = blobName,
                    PartNumber = partNumber
                };
```